# Tridion 2013 SP1 The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

Tags: 2013-sp1

There are two different issues:

1)  Multiple authentication prompts when access CMS from internet:

This issue is being resolved using https

2) CMS server unable to pull users from AD:

Application communication with AD has been verified and also backend authentication with AD is working fine. But from the  application console if a search is done on AD it is not working as expected. We have identified that application may not be able to pull the user list

If I start add new user by search by domain, search initiated and aborted.. it's says Loading.. but nothing happening some how it's aborted..

Error message found on EventViewer:

> The communication object,
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServerSessionPreambleConnectionReader+ServerFramingDuplexSessionChannel,
>   cannot be used for communication because it has been Aborted.
>   Component: Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService Errorcode: 0 User: NT
>   AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE  StackTrace Information Details:    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.ThrowIfDisposedOrNotOpen()
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.OutputChannel.Send(Message message,
>   TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransactionDuplexChannelGeneric`1.Send(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContextBase.Reply(Message message,
>   TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.Reply(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)

This below error message some time getting this in CME notification window:

> at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout)

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue because of sophos firewall, It's blocked all the RPC ports.

We allowed the RPC dynamic port range and then it's working fine.

Answer (score 5):

Obtaining a list of users from a Windows domain with many users is known to be notoriously slow (and may even lead to timeouts, which seem to be happening on your environment).
A common work-around is to configure your AD as an (LDAP) Directory Service in CM and select "Directory Service" instead of "Domain" when adding users through the CME.
Another work-around is to create new Users directly on the CM API (Core Service) instead of through the CME.

Comment: BTW, configuring your AD as Directory Service is a good idea in general. It allows you to use the "group sync" feature on your AD, That is: map CM Groups to AD Groups and manage the group memberships in AD rather than in CM.